# Migrating from Apache 2.2 to 2.4, ssl.conf is ignored

Tags: apache-2.4, migration, httpd, centos7

I'm rolling out a test installation of EL7 with Apache 2.4.  I copied my existing `/etc/httpd/conf.d/ssl.conf` to the new system, set up selinux, verified all the cert paths were kosher and `systemctl httpd start` started the service.  Apache is running error free.

The problem is that my ssl.conf file is ignored.  I'm being shown the default Apache page using

I tried moving `/etc/httpd/conf.d/ssl.conf` to `/etc/httpd/conf.modules.d/` (first removing the existing 00-ssl.conf file), with the same result.

Where am I getting it wrong?

**Edit 1**
The error log shows this:

```
AH01630: client denied by server configuration: /www/virtualhosts/example.com
```

Where my ssl config has this:

```
DocumentRoot /www/virtualhosts/example.com
```

and

```
ll /www/virtualhosts/example.com
total 4
-rw-r--r--. 1 apache apache 21 Dec 18 14:32 index.php
```

index.php consists of:

```
<p>Hello World
```

I'm at a loss.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Got it.  Apache 2.4 has additional security features.  I needed to add this to  `/etc/httpd/conf/http.conf` and restart the service.

```
<Directory "/www/virtualhosts/example.com">
        Options Indexes FollowSymLinks
        AllowOverride None
        Require all granted
</Directory>
```

I can haz website.

Also, I moved the default 00-ssl.conf file back in place (`/etc/httpd/conf.modules.d/`), and moved `ssl.conf` back to `/etc/httpd/conf.d/ssl.conf`.

Restarted the service and all is still well.

Comment: Do not forget to mark your answer as correct, thanks.